Синонимизировать [маршрутизация] и [route]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

route (131 вопрос) нет описания
маршрутизация (369 вопросов) описание есть

Основная - маршрутизация, т. к. она на русском.

они все-таки отличаются. как правило  маршрутизация - ближе к сетевым протоколам/устройствам, а route - скорее к правилам обработки урлов фреймворками

А как насчет позаменять метку route на маршрутизацию руками? Заодно выяснить всгда ли они синонимы. Если да - сделать синоним. Если нет - добавить описание.

@Kromster, наверное так и надо будет сделать.
